# jquery ui tabs select doesn't seem to work in 1.10.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The following program works in earlier releases of jQuery UI, but it does not work in the Latest release though.

The select property does not call the function in the `handleSelect` variable. See the following fiddle: [working tabs program](http://jsfiddle.net/laurence/uhuNg/)

Here is my code for jQuery UI 1.10.3

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Tabs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabSelect.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="myTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#a">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#b">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="a">This is the content panel linked to the first tab, it is shown by default.</div>
    <div id="b">This is the content panel linked to the second tab, it is shown when its tab is clicked.</div>  
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.effect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.effect-blind.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        var handleSelect = function(e, tab) {

            $("<p></p>", {
                text: "Tab at index " + tab.index + " selected",
                "class": "status-message ui-corner-all"
            }).appendTo(".ui-tabs-nav", "#myTabs").fadeOut(5000, function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        },
        tabOpts = {
            select : handleSelect
        };
        $("#myTabs").tabs({ select: handleSelect});
    })(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#tabs) for jQuery UI 1.10

> Removed `select` event; use `beforeActivate`
>
> (#7154) The `select` event has been removed in favor of `beforeActivate`. [See the 1.9 deprecation notice](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-select-method) for full details.

Here is a <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/uhuNg/3/)</kbd>

Replaced

```
$("#myTabs").tabs({ select: handleSelect});
```

with

```
$("#myTabs").tabs({ beforeActivate: handleSelect});
```

**EDIT**

Just noticed that your indexes won't work with 1.10 either. Updated my fiddle!
See the [docu](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate).

```
var handleSelect = function(e, tab) {

    $("<p></p>", {
        //this is new
        text: "Tab at index " + tab.newTab.index() + " selected",
        "class": "status-message ui-corner-all"
        }).appendTo(".ui-tabs-nav", "#myTabs").fadeOut(5000, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! It's always a good idea to check the upgrade guide before upgrading. :) Thanks for accepting my answer